# Java code with timestamp

Tags: java, timer

I am recently working with an algorithm and implementing it in JAVA. In which I put a timer for computing the time taken by particular phase of algorithm. The code for timer is something like this.

```
static long start = 0;
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
System.out.printf("Took %.3f%n", time/1e3);
```

And the output of this code is

```
Took 6.807
```

Now what is the unit of time in this output. Is it millisecond or microsecond or nano second or just second? And what needs to be done with this code to get the output time in millisecond? Thank You in advance.

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the current time in milliseconds (hence "millis"). If you divide your time measurement by a thousand (as you do with `time/1e3`), you are converting it to seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the explanation:

- `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the current time in milliseconds. Check the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()).
- Dividing it with `1e3` (it's 1*10<sup>3</sup>, that's 1000) converts the time to seconds, because one second contains 1000 milliseconds.

However I don't understand the usage of the key word `static` in the first line.

Comment: Got my answer, sir. Thank You.